# Boost compiled with Clang thinks it's being compiled by MinGW

Tags: c++, boost, clang

This is rather puzzling. I use MSVC for all my work on this machine, and just use clang for a tool that needs AST parsing.

Now with Clang, when I try to parse a file which includes some Boost headers, I get this:

```
<SourceLocation file '[..]boost_1_59_0/boost/config/platform/win32.hpp', line 17, column 12>
'_mingw.h' file not found
```

The line including `_mingw.h` in `win32.hpp` should only be evaluated when `__MINGW32__` is defined.

I am surely not defining it myself or anywhere in my project files, so I am at a loss. Where could I look to resolve this?

Debugging this is rather tricky, and googling gets me mostly stuff from people who are actually using MinGW, but no one in my situation (Clang being mistaken for MinGW).

Comment: What are the exact Boost headers you include? Could you maybe post a minimal example to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I would guess that Clang defines \_\_MINGW32\_\_ as one of its built-in macros when Clang is built for windows.  You can probably turn it off with the /U flag.

Comment: The -U option worked right away ! Silly me, I thought it wouldn't work as I guessed it was defined afterwards in some boost file, so I didn't even try it.
It happens when including `<boost/pool/object_pool.hpp>`
I don't really understand though why clang would define this ? I believe they are two different compilers ? (this has always confused me)

Comment: MinGW isn't a compiler, it's (as its name says) a minimal GNU environment for Windows. It includes the GCC compiler. But Clang for Windows can also target it, in which case it predefines `__MINGW32__` so as to identify itself as targetting MinGW, as opposed to being in MSVC compatibility mode (its other running mode), where it defines `__MSCVER` instead.

Comment: How do you activate MSVC compatibility mode then ? Documentation is inexistant. I applied all the flags mentioned there : http://clang.llvm.org/docs/MSVCCompatibility.html. But that didn't have the effect of defining `__MSCVER` instead of `__MINGW32__`  ....
The flags I set are `-fdelayed-template-parsing` `-fms-compatibility`, `-fms-extensions` and `-fmsc-version=1800`